# What can be coerced into an integer in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, if you try to do `2 + nil`, for example, you get

> TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Integer

but, this made me wonder if there is anything that can be coerced into an `Integer`. A lot of times `Integer`s are coerced to other numeric types, like here

```
(2 + Rational('1/2')).class 
# => Rational
(2 + 0.5).class
# => Float
(2 + 1i).class
# => Complex
```

And, Booleans in Ruby don't get coerced to `Integer`. So, what does get coerced into an `Integer`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for hypothetical general knowledge, not assistance a specific problem.

Comment: Is this question implying _types_ and _class_ are the same thing? Are they?

Comment: Using `Integer(...)` to cast things is a very heavy-handed approach. Usuaully `.to_i` is sufficient, plus allows for passing around objects that can emit numbers *if necessary*.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 classes and types are not the same in Ruby. For example everything that responds to `to_ary` coercible to an array, and many core methods will throw a `TypeError` when they cannot convert an argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby arbitrary classes can choose to be coercible to other types by defining a `coerce` method. This is described in detail [here](http://wiki.c2.com/?RubyCoerce).

Comment: +100 extra upvotes for a wiki link. Thanks for taking me down the memory lane!

Answer (score 4):

There are four protocols for types coercion/conversion in Ruby, three general ones, and one specific to arithmetic operations on numbers.

## one-letter type conversion

When objects can meaningfully be represented as an instance of another class, then they respond to one-letter type conversion methods such as `to_s`, `to_i`, `to_f`, etc. The bar for responding to one of those is very low: if there is *any* way that an object can be represented as, say, an integer that is not completely bogus, then it can respond to `to_i`. E.g. it kinda-sorta makes sense to represent `nil` as the integer `0`, therefore `nil` responds to `to_i`. Likewise, it kinda-sorta makes sense to represent `nil` as the empty string, therefore it responds to `to_s`.

## multi-letter type conversion

This is much stricter. Only when an object can be reasonably be interpreted as being of *the same type* as an instance of a different class, is it allowed to respond to `to_str`, `to_int`, etc. For example, there are 10 implementations of `to_i` in the Ruby core library, but only 4 for `to_int`.

In pure OO, it shouldn't matter what class an object is an instance of. If an object behaves like an integer, then it *is*, for all intents and purposes, an integer, no matter what class it is an instance of. Unfortunately, Ruby is not purely OO. For example, on YARV, `Array#[]` is implemented by indexing into a C array using a machine integer. (On JRuby, it is indexing into a Java array, and similarly on Opal, MRuby, Rubinius, IronRuby, MagLev, …) This means that only objects that are *actual* instances of the `Integer` class can be used for array indexing, because the Ruby implementation only knows how to extract a machine integer (Java integer, …) from an `Integer`, but not from an arbitrary object that behaves like an integer; it knows what the internal memory structure of an `Integer` looks like, but it doesn't know what the internal memory structure of your `MyInteger` looks like.

But, as an escape hatch, `Array#[]` will try to convert the object to an integer using `to_int` first. So, it's not fully OO, but at least at gives you the option to participate in array indexing by converting yourself to an integer.

Likewise, the `&` unary ampersand prefix "convert-to-block" operator *theoretically* only works with `Proc`s, but it will call `to_proc` first, to give the object a chance to convert itself to a `Proc`.

## capital letter type conversion

There are a couple of factory methods defined in `Kernel` whose name matches a core class, e.g. `Kernel#Integer`, `Kernel#Float`, etc. Those are intended to convert a wide range of objects to their respective classes. They are in some sense much more loose, in that they accept a much wider range of objects than the multi-letter type conversions. But in some sense they are also stricter, since they are allowed to raise exceptions. The `to_` methods aren't allowed to raise exceptions: they either exist, and then they *must* work, or they don't exist at all.

`Kernel#Integer` accepts a string, for example, and will try to parse it as an integer.

## arithmetic operations coercion

This protocol is specific to numbers, and to arithmetic operations. When you send a number a message for an arithmetic operation, and pass an argument that the number doesn't know how to deal with, it will ask that argument to `coerce` the pair of numbers to a more general pair of types.

So, let's say, you have `a + b`, and `a` doesn't know what to do with `b`, then within `a`'s `+` method, it will call `b.coerce(self)`, and `b` will respond with `[a_converted_to_a_more_general_type, b_converted_to_a_more_general_type]`, after which `a` will retry calling `a_converted_to_a_more_general_type + b_converted_to_a_more_general_type`:

```
class Roman < Numeric
  def initialize(str)
    # dummy implementation for the sake of this example
    @num = 5 if str == 'V'
  end

  def coerce(other)
    puts "`coerce` called with #{other.inspect}, which is a #{other.class}"
    [other, @num]
  end

  def to_int
    puts '`to_int` called'
    @num
  end
end

2 + Roman.new('V')
# `coerce` called with 2, which is a Integer
#=> 7

('a'..'g').to_a[Roman.new('V')]
# `to_int` called
#=> 'f'
```

Answer (score -1):

If a string contains digits only it can be coerced to an Integer:

```
Integer('1') # => 1
Integer('1.0') # => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1.0"
```

This can be useful if you're trying to make sure that a value that was input was truly an integer instead of a float or whether it had any other "junk" in it:

```
Float('1.0') # => 1.0
```

If you want to coerce values to an integer, and are not trying to validate input, then you probably want to use `to_i` instead, which gives you a better chance of getting a usable result without an exception occurring:

```
1.to_i  # => 1
'1'.to_i  # => 1
Time.now.to_i # => 1485640961
''.to_i # => 0
nil.to_i  # => 0

1.to_i + nil.to_i # => 1
```